# Configuring Blackberry Eclipse plugin for 4.70 or 5.0 components

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, components, blackberry-os-v5

I am looking for help in configuring the Blackberry development environment.  In fact, it is quite a frustrating process.  The blackberry site is pretty useless.  Between links that have been moved, details that are assumed and documents that are out of date it is proving very difficult to get anywhere with blackberry development.

Pheww, now that my rant is done.  Here is my problem:

I have finally got the JDE for Eclipse working (that is a story in itself).  However, my blackberry workspace is only giving me the option of targeting the 4.5 JDE components.  How do I update it to use the 4.7 components?

It would be preferable to have step-by-step instructions but I would appreciate any help that can be provided.

Here are the details:

I have Java jdk1.6.0_14

Eclipse version 3.4.1

I have installed the Blackberry JDE 4.7

I have installed the Blackberry JDE Component Package 4.7

I have installed the Blackberry Smartphone simulators 4.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Totally agreed - it's not at all obvious what to do.  I've never had luck using their update site, so I just download and install the component packs manually:

1. Download the "Eclipse Software Update for the BlackBerry JDE v4.7 Component Pack" from the BlackBerry developer zone (it's a zip file)
2. From Eclipse open the Help menu and choose Software Updates
3. Click on the Available Software tab
4. Click Add Site
5. Choose Archive and select your zip file
6. Make sure everything under the JDE 4.7 tree is checked
7. Click Install and continue through the wizard

Comment: the first step was the key.  getting the name of the file to search for led me to the zip file and then the rest was straight forward.

Comment: can u please provide a link to download these components packs,i cldnt find from googling please help!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are a life saver!!!!!!!!!!! This worked perfectly. I understand the frustration. If this. If this doesn't work I would recommend deleteing the entire directory and reinstalling eclipse.

You should already have JDK installed:
This is what I downloaded for 64bit windows:jdk-6u16-windows-x64.exe get one that matches your OS. Should be jdk version 6.

I installed this version: Should work for windows x86 and 64bit:
eclipse-java-ganymede-SR2-win32.zip
Other versions shouldn't work. has to be 3.4 but not 3.5 (gallileo) and it has to be for java.

Then I installed the plugin. Then I followed the instructions above and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse-java-ganymede-SR2-win32.zip does not work with the 64-bit JDK.

You have to use eclipse-SDK-3.4.1-win32-x86_64 with the 64-bit JDK. Once you use these two things together and install the Eclipse Plugin, the installation works fine, but I always get "Cannot find RIMIDEWin32Util.dll.  This is a required component of the IDE." and then "Cannot find RIMUsbJni.dll. Without this dll the IDE cannot connect to USB enabled handhelds. Add RIMUsbJni to java.library.path".  Both of the supposedly missing files are located in my workspace path under .metadata.plugins\net.rim.eide.bootstrapper\installDlls.  I have placed those two files pretty much everywhere I could think of, even c:\windows\system32, and it still claims to not be able to find these files.

Now for the fix....

You **can** use eclipse-java-ganymede-SR2-win32.zip with the 32-bit JDK.  Make sure you add the JDK\bin to your %PATH% environment variable. You can then install the Blackberry JDK Plugin and Component Pack and everything will work!

Note: In order to "Configure Blackberry Workspace" from the Blackberry menu, you must first create a Blackberry project.  Found this out the hard way.